# Header Transfer Encoding:Chunked and request empty

Tags: asp.net, iis-8

This is a Webforms based asp.net application on .net framework 4.6. While doing an IdP initiated SSO via SAML we encountered a problem where some users have intermittent login issues. Reason is when the login attempt was made on our side application doesn't have the SAML Response in the request body (IdP Post the saml response to a given url).

So we used SAML Message Decoder extension to troubleshoot and found out that the SAML Response is actually available but it's not coming to our application Request object. So we tried to dump everything in request via;

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)

{

using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(pathxx))

{

using (Stream receiveStream = Request.InputStream)

{

using (StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8))

{

xxx += readStream.ReadToEnd();

}

}

sw.WriteLine(xxx);

}

 

}
```

This confirmed that SAML Response was not coming to the application even though the SAML Message Decoder shows the SAML Response. So basically our partners side is clear. They are sending what we need.

Further digging showed that whenever we don't get the SAML Response, The Response header has  Transfer Encoding:Chunked and there is NO Content-Length. this happens in Chrome and Edge. Firefox this was not a problem.

There are quite a few related issues but I couldn't find a solid technical answer why this happens, whether this is a fault of browsers or web servers(We are on IIS 8.5 & IIS 10). Have anyone out there faced this on a ASP.Net site and got it to solve?

Comment: I think your issue is too broad. It is necessary to figure out the issue caused by IIS or browser. 1) So is there any easy way to reproduce this issue? Please also provide more sample code and detailed steps. 2) Which version of Edge and Chrome are you using? 3) Is there any warning or errors in console? 4) Which format are you expecting about saml response? I check the document about [Transfer-Encoding:chunked](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Transfer-Encoding) and Content-Length. The two cannot exsit at same time.

Comment: 5) You can check the log on IIS to see whether the request and URL is correct. 6) Check the event viewer to see whether any error message has been reocrded.

Comment: I was able to fix this using ashx. I put the same code in to the ashx file and it started to working. Does anyone know why aspx and ashx works differently.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, because of the addition of control functions in aspx, it focuses on the handling of **complete life cycle processing of request** and the rendering of the page.

While ashx focuses on request processing, it only has a single **ProcessRequest** method,so it is more used to process ajax calls.

In [SAML SSO](https://developers.onelogin.com/saml), I noticed that SAML SSO works by transferring the user’s identity from one place (the identity provider) to another (the service provider). This is done through an exchange of digitally signed XML documents.

There is a Generic Handler in ashx, which is used to perform specific tasks without creating HTML content, and when **processing XML content**, it has advantages over aspx.